# takes this string message as an input and returns a corresponding value in terms of a number

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

For instance 1 is made of 2 dashes, 8 is made of 7 dashes and so on.write a function that takes this string message as an input and returns a corresponding value in terms of a number. This number is the count of dashes in the string message.

Comment: Why is the question in the rails section? What language are you using?

Comment: This sounds like *part* of a homework question.

Comment: @thisfeller Surely not English.

Comment: how does your string look like?

Answer (score 1):

String has a `count` method:

```
"abc--de-f-".count('-') #=> 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Just get a string with nothing but the dashes from your input string, and then check the length of that string:

```
dash_string = input_string.gsub(/[^-]/, '')
number = dash_string.length
```

You might want to subtract 1 from that answer based on your examples, bearing in mind that a string with no dashes would turn into -1 in that case.